# Which method should I use to store and retrive images for an android application?

Tags: android, image, performance, encoding

I am developing an application that requires me to retrieve multiple images from a Cache database and then display them on an Application.

At the moment i write the images to binary array's and then convert them to bitmap images on the application, but the Base64 string is about 30% larger that the actual image.

What encoding method should i use to reduce the overhead involved in storing these images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the images in the SDCard, in the device cache, or in a database. Not sure which you mean but here are some guides.

This post explains how to store an image in any location on the sdcard:
[Save bitmap to location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location)

This one explains how to store in the device cache partition: [Android, Saving and loading a bitmap in cache from different activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540386/android-saving-and-loading-a-bitmap-in-cache-from-diferent-activities)

And [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20200718180158/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/how-to-insert-image-data-to-sqlite.html) explains saving and retrieving bitmaps to/from a database.

Comment: I do not want to store the images on the phone, i want an encoding method to reduce the size of the packet that is sent to and from my database.